# Print function in python error

Tags: python-2.7

I have just started learning python 2.7, and as every new learner i am still getting accustomed to the syntax that python uses. I tried to write this code:

```
name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
print 'Hi, %s.' % (name)
```

I guess the output for the above program should be:

```
Hi, What is your name?
```

But i am getting the output as:

```
What is your name?
```

After pressing `enter` key, i get another output:

```
Hi, .
```

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem, it does exactly what you tell it to.

`raw_input` prints the string argument (as a prompt), and reads input from the user until the first newline, returning the text it has read. This is exactly what happens (try typing some text before hitting Enter). Then the second line takes that text and puts it into the formatting string, printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

The `raw_input` function is used to take input form the prompt. The string you passed in function will be printed on the prompt followed by your input which gets completed (in sense of python) with the pressing of 'enter key'.
After that the next line `print 'Hi, %s.' % (name)` will get printed showing the name entered by user in the prompt, which, I assume, is `None` in your case as you are pressing enter key without any input.